# Difference between 2 numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, numbers

I need the perfect algorithm or C# function to calculate the difference (distance) between 2 decimal numbers.

For example the difference between:
**100** and **25** is **75**
**100** and **-25** is **125**
**-100** and **-115** is **15**
**-500** and **100** is **600**

Is there a C# function or a very elegant algorithm to calculate this or I have to go and handle every case separately with *if*s.

If there is such a function or algorithm, which one is it?

Comment: The examples you give are all integers - is that the case for all the numbers you test or are some floating point? If so, then you may have to settle for testing for when they're "close enough" - i.e. checking if the difference is less than some threshold.

Comment: why downvoted? this seems like a fair question for someone unfamiliar with Math.Abs

Comment: +1, no need for downvoting a perfectly ok question

Comment: I think the phrase ' or I have to go and handle every case separately with ifs.' shows clearly this question was asked tongue in chhek

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
public decimal FindDifference(decimal nr1, decimal nr2)
{
  return Math.Abs(nr1 - nr2);
}
```

Comment: Of course there is no need in putting this code into a separate function but it was more for clarifying

Comment: Crashes when `(nr1 - nr2) = Int32.MinValue` - question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702478/difference-between-two-large-numbers-c-sharp)

Comment: @cz Crash is pretty obvious for `Int32.MinValue`. The reason why this happens is very trivial as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265381/465053). The range of number data types is always like `-x` to `(x-1)`. Of course, if I try to accomodate `+x` (absolute value of `Int32.MinValue`) in the same data type to obtain the absolute value then it is bound fail :)

Answer (score 37):

```
result = Math.Abs(value1 - value2);
```

Comment: He wanted to say Math. Math is the .Net class that contains static methods for trigonometric, logarithmic, and other common mathematical functions

Comment: :p  Can't believe it took 2 years for someone to pick me up on that :)

Comment: **Word of extreme caution**: *This code will crash* when `value1-value2` is equal to `Int32.MinValue` because of `System.OverflowException` exception. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38702478/465053).

Comment: *Countering myself* - Crash is pretty obvious for `Int32.MinValue`. The reason why this happens is very trivial as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265381/465053). The range of number data types is always like `-x` to `(x-1)`. Of course, if I try to accomodate `+x` (absolute value of `Int32.MinValue`) in the same data type to obtain the absolute value then it is bound fail.

Comment: the endpoints of the range of _signed_ integers are "off by one" ( -32,768 and 32,767 for 16 bits, for example)

Comment: +1 I think this is the most elegant solution overall. A note on performance: I tested Math.Abs vs `if (value1 < 0) { value1 = (value1 * -1); }` in a loop that ran 10 million times and I found the IF evaluation runs in 40% less time.

Answer (score 30):

Just adding this, as nobody wrote it here:

While you can surely use

```
Math.Abs(number1 - number2);
```

which is the easiest solution (and accepted answer), I wonder nobody wrote out what Abs actually does. Here's a solution that works in *Java, C, C# and every other language with C like syntax*:

```
int result = number1 - number2;
if (result < 0) {
    result *= -1;
}
```

It's that simple. You can also write it like this:

```
int result = number1 > number2 ? number1 - number2 : number2 - number1;
```

The last one could be even faster once it got compiled; both have one if and one subtraction, but the first one has a multiplication in some cases, the last one has not. Why only in some cases? Some CPUs have a "swap sign" operation and the compiler recognizes what `*= -1` does, it just swaps the sign, so instead of a multiplication, it will issue a swap sign operation for CPUs that offer it and this operation is as fast as a CPU operation can get (usually one clock cycle).

The first code example is actually doing what Abs is doing in most implementations to make use of "swap sign" where supported, the last one will be faster on CPUs that have no "swap sign" and were multiplications are more expensive than additions (on modern CPUs they are often equally fast).

Comment: I'm surprised no one has said anything about this does not work for all integers. I'm sure the difference between int.MaxValue and int.MinValue is not -1

Comment: @Aelphaeis Your edit is bogus; please don't edit posts unless you fully understood a topic. Of course it works just fine for negative integers. E.g. `number1` is `100` and `number2` is `-100`: `100 - (-100) = 200` which is correct. Or see this `(-50) - (-80) = 30`, which is correct, too. The reason why it does not work for `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue` is because the difference between those two is `4'294'967'295` but the biggest number that fits into an `int` is `2'147'483'647` and thus you cause it to overflow twice.

Comment: I had realized that and actually made a second edit. I guess it was never approved.

Comment: Use `result = -result` instead of `result *= -1`. That's what the `-` (negative) operator is for, after all.

Comment: Really, thank you for this @Mecki, I needed that formula.

Comment: I like what you did with the `*=`, I hadn't seen that done before. I would even put the whole thing on one line like this
`int result = number1 - number2; if (result < 0) { result *= -1; } //get absolute value`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible in C#, you may need to look at implementing it in Assembler

Comment: Someone who doesn't know the maths behind this solution isn't necessarily going to know if it's possible, especially when they have a working alternative. Dry humour is impossible to detect under those circumstances, so downvotes are entirely reasonable. Funny or not, it's wrong information.

Comment: use <humor> </humor>

or a ;)

Comment: The original question had a tag that said that a sense of humour was needed. In that context, all funny answers are allowed!

Comment: It's not impossible to detect dry humor here. C'mon "Assembler"? An invitation down any road of torture is obviously programmer wit. But I agree some markup or an emoji always helps.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen though, to be fair, the user who posted this answer was the one who edited that tag into the question, not the OP

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it in enterprise projects:

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static T Difference<T>(object x1, object x2) where T : IConvertible
        {
            decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(x1.ToString());
            decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(x2.ToString());

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Math.Abs(d1-d2), typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

and testing:

```
namespace MixedTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ExtensionsTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Difference_int_Test()
        {
            int res2 = Functions.Difference<int>(5, 7);
            int res3 = Functions.Difference<int>(-3, 0);
            int res6 = Functions.Difference<int>(-3, -9);
            int res8 = Functions.Difference<int>(3, -5);

            Assert.AreEqual(19, res2 + res3 + res6 + res8);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Difference_float_Test()
        {
            float res2_1 = Functions.Difference<float>(5.1, 7.2);
            float res3_1 = Functions.Difference<float>(-3.1, 0);
            double res5_9 = Functions.Difference<double>(-3.1, -9);
            decimal res8_3 = Functions.Difference<decimal>(3.1, -5.2);

            Assert.AreEqual((float)2.1, res2_1);
            Assert.AreEqual((float)3.1, res3_1);
            Assert.AreEqual(5.9, res5_9);
            Assert.AreEqual((decimal)8.3, res8_3);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ToString() is expensive considering it's an int or float you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :),
returns the difference between two values.
I have tested it and it has worked for me in all cases, also with decimals!!!

```
public static double Diference (double a,double b) {
        return ((System.Math.Max(a,b)-System.Math.Min(a,b)));
    }
```