# Calculating the Difference between 2 numbers in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

I know a similar question has been asked before with C#
[Difference between 2 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339961/difference-between-2-numbers)

But I need to know if objective-c provides some function to find the difference between 2 numbers, (2 NSIntegers, to be specific)

For example the difference between:

100 and 25 is 75

-25 and 100 is 125

100 and -25 is also 125

-100 and -115 is 15

//I know I'm using the same example as the previous

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: abs(value1 - value2) gives absolut difference between to numbers. This value is always positive and exactly what your are looking for.

Comment: I suggest you change XCode (both in the question and in the tags) with Objective-C as this has nothing to do with XCode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think basic math is something that every programming language does: `abs(num1 - num2)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that abs() works for integers and will automatically round any non-integer arguments in addition to performing the absolute value function. My programs tend to be full of fractional data so I end up using fabs() a lot.